# Prove that a finite union of closed sets is also closed (using limit points)

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, solution-verification

Let $F_i$ be a family of closed sets, then we know that $\bigcup_{i=1}^nF_i$ is closed.

Proving that statement is equivalent to proving:

> If $p$ is a limit point of $\bigcup_{i=1}^nF_i$ then $p\in\bigcup_{i=1}^nF_i$

It is easy to prove the contrapositive: if $p\notin\bigcup_{i=1}^nF_i$ then $p$ is not a limit point of $\bigcup_{i=1}^nF_i$

However I tried the following direct proof that I am sure it is wrong because it does not use the countable nature of the union. I want to know where I am making a mistake in the following chain of reasonings:

If $p$ is a limit point of $\bigcup_{i=1}^nF_i$ then in every neighbourhood there is a point $q\neq p$, such that $q\in \bigcup_{i=1}^nF_i$. Since $q\in \bigcup_{i=1}^nF_i$ then $q$ belongs to at least one $F_i$, then (and this is what I suspect is false) $p$ is a limit point of $F_i$. Since $F_i$ is closed, then $p\in F_i$, then $p\in\bigcup_{i=1}^nF_i$.

Therefore: If $p$ is a limit point of $\bigcup_{i=1}^nF_i$ then $p\in\bigcup_{i=1}^nF_i$.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: First, it should be "in every neighborhood there is a point $q\ne p$ such that $q\in\bigcup_1^n F_i$". But the main mistake is that the point $q$ which you can find in this neighborhood need not be in the same $F_i$ for all neighborhoods. Look at $F_n=\{1/n\}$, where $n\in\Bbb N$, and $p=0$, then for every neighborhood of $0$, you can find some $1/n\in F_n$.

Comment: Thank you very much Stefan for the correction (I am editing it asap) and for your answer. Is it possible to prove the proposition the way I tried? (i.e. without using the contrapositive)

Comment: The easiest way of proving your statement is in my opinion is by using the fact that a subset $F$ of a set $X$ is closed iff $X-F$ is open. Then applying De Morgans Law your problem reduces to proving that a finite intersection of open subsets is open, which is a definition in general topological spaces.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I am ooking to prove in that particular way, which I know it's not the easiest way.

Comment: I guess your proof by contraposition goes like this: *If $p\not\in\bigcup_1^n F_i$, then for every $i$ we can find a neighborhood $U_i$ of $p$ disjoint from $F_i$ since $F_i$ is closed. Then the intersection of these $U_i$ is a neighborhood of $p$ disjoint from $\bigcup_1^n F_i$. Thus it's not a limit point of the union*. I think that's the most direct proof, and the proof as you intend it would still secretly use this arguing.

Comment: That's exactly the proof, and uses the fact that you need the minimum of the radii of the neighborhoods. And there you use the fact that the union is countable. I want to use that "min" (or max maybe) in the modus ponens proof.

Comment: Note that the reasoning in the proof in my comment is more or less DeMorgan's Law (the point where I say that the intersection of the $U_i$ is disjoint from the union of the $F_i$), which is what @TheOscillator suggests.

Comment: If you are talking about metric spaces (as opposed to general topological spaces), you could  do this: *For every $n\in\Bbb N$ pick a point $q_n\ne p$ in $F_{i_n}\cap B(z, 1/n)$. This gives you a sequence of points in $\bigcup F_i$ converging to $p$. Since there are only finitely many $F_i$, one of them, say $F_j$, must contain a subsequence of $(q_n)_n$ converging to $p$. Thus $p\in F_j$.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know from your other questions you like to see rigorous answers; so I thought I'd do the same on this one too. I did this a slightly longer way since I do not know which definition of closed you are using (so I used a standard definition of open)

def. $U$ is open $\Leftrightarrow \forall x \in U\; \exists \varepsilon >0 : B(x, \varepsilon) \subset U$

def. $x$ is a limit point of $U \Leftrightarrow \forall \varepsilon >0 \, (B(x, \varepsilon)\setminus \{x\}) \cap U \neq \emptyset$

1. $\forall i\, F_i$ is closed
2. $p$ is a limit point of $\cup_{i=1}^n F_i$
3. $\forall \varepsilon >0 \, B(p, \varepsilon)\setminus \{p\} \cup (\cap_{i=1}^n F_i) \neq \emptyset$
4. $\forall \varepsilon >0 \, B(p, \varepsilon) \cap (\cup_{i=1}^n F_i) \neq \emptyset$
5. Suppose $p \not \in \cup_{i=1}^n F_i$
6. $p \in (\cup_{i=1}^n F_i)^c$
7. $p \in \cap_{i=1}^n F_i^c $
8. $\forall i \leq n : p \in F_i^c$
9. $p \in F_k^c$
10. $F_k^c$ is open
11. $\forall x \in F_k^c\; \exists \varepsilon >0 : B(x, \varepsilon)\subset F_k^c$
12. $\exists \varepsilon >0 : B(p, \varepsilon)\subset F_k^c$
13. $B(p, \varepsilon)\subset F_k^c$
14. $\forall i \, B(p, \varepsilon)\subset F_i^c$
15. $B(p, \varepsilon) \subset  \cap_{i=1}^n F_i^c $
16. $B(p, \varepsilon) \cap (\cap_{i=1}^n F_i^c)^c = \emptyset$
17. $B(p, \varepsilon) \cap (\cup_{i=1}^n F_i) = \emptyset$
18. $ \exists \varepsilon >0: B(p, \varepsilon) \cap (\cup_{i=1}^n F_i) = \emptyset$
19. $\lnot \forall \varepsilon >0 \, B(p, \varepsilon) \cap (\cup_{i=1}^n F_i) \neq \emptyset$
20. Contradition
21. $p \in \cup_{i=1}^n F_i$

Notice that I did not explicitly use the fact that $n$ is finite. This is a very subtle point in the proof that is used implicitly in steps 6 - 8; As a counter example in the case $n \rightarrow \infty$, let $(X, d)$ be a metric space, and $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \cup_{i=1}^{n} F_i = X$ where $F_i \subset F_{i+1}$. Can you see how this would nullify this proof?

Comment: Excellent job. In that case, step 6. would be false because the empty set has no elements? Not sure if that's correct.

Comment: Essentially yes, there is a little bit of nuance when you sit down and write it out.

Comment: But, what about if $U^{n}_{i}F_{i}=X$?

Comment: then there is nothing to prove

Comment: You are absolutely right! Every $p$ is in $X$.

Answer (score 0):

Use the infinite pigeon-hole principle: If aninfinite set is presented as the union of finitely many subsets,at least one subset is infinite.So if a sequence p(n)  converges to p, where each p(n) belongs to some F(j), then,for at least one j, there are infinitely many n for which p(n) belongs to F(j), so p belongs to this F(j).